# What's the purpose of dot operation in SQL?

Tags: sql

Might be a dumb question, still I'm a beginner with datacamp.

I am wondering at the 1st line what is the point of the dots

```
c.code, c.name, c.region
```

when I could simply write as

```
code, name, region
```

both with the same output?

[with dot operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtYIj.png)

[without dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9H8w.png)

My guess is, for both tables `Countries` and `Population` have the same column `code`, hence if I do not specify, which `code` I want my data to take out from (either from `Population` or `Countries`), then SQL will just take from the later (which is population in this case)

**HOWEVER** I will eventually be INNER JOINING both tables with `code`, so we are back to, dot operation is useless for inner join?

Comment: Read about using _aliases_ in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! ok.. i have read about aliases (1 https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp ; 2 https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alias-syntax.htm, 3 https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/alias.php )
 I could have phrase the question better or preharps i still could not understand.
 it's not really about how aliasing have benefits of (to give temp name, save time typing)
 but more of why even alias when we do not even need to alias (in my example)

Comment: @castlesand If you don't need to do it, don't do it. It's an option, not a necessity

Comment: @Tomalak For a query involving _more_ than one table, aliases should always be used.  For a query just covering a single table, it is usually optional.

Comment: Dot is only necessary when joining two or more tables which have same column names. Specially in CTEs

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Anybody who's really into a lot of repetitive typing is welcome to do without aliases even for multi-table queries. :)

Comment: See the comment by @Meyssam for the reason for using aliases in queries with two or more tables.

Comment: thank you everyone ! i'll just take it as because of similar column names xx

Comment: Tables often have 20+ columns, when writing a query involving multiple tables you don't want to cross check the columns lists of the two tables before deciding whether or not to use aliases. The reflex is so ingrained in some people that they'll use aliases even when the query only involve a single table.